# How to implement function addTodo in a todo app?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm making a todo app and i wanna make the function that whenever i type in the textbox and click on the add button, my todo item will be rendered but i'm kinda stuck in making it...i'm a begginer so does anyone have any "easy to understand" code can you help me to get this function done? Thank you so much!

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  addTodo = () => {};

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="add todo"
        />
        <button onClick={addTodo} type="submit">
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of achieving that is to render a lsit of ToDo items below your form. Every time you submit, you append the new value to the list!

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]) // Initialize an empty list


  // you can use the submit itself, no need for an extra addTodo function
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, value]) // <-- append value to the list
    setValue('') // Clear the value
  };


  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
          type="text"
          placeholder="add todo"
        />
        <button type="submit">
          Add
        </button>
      </form>
      {todos.map(todoValue => <h1>ToDo: {todoValue}</h1>)}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Other than that, I would suggest taking a course or following a tutorial for this kind of app.

Also, StackOverflow is usually meant for specific questions, and not "How do I do this", just a tip for next questions!

Comment: Thank you. However your codes not working for me...:https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-cdn-cy3w4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Edited my answer. It was missing a closing parenthesis. Please read the errors, it will help you grow so much as a developer!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answe! However, when i hit submit, the old value seems to still stay, is there any way to fix this?

Comment: add the value prop to your input! It's currently uncontrolled. `<input value={value}/>`

Answer (score 0):

To create ToDo list & update it when new Todo adding follow the below steps or you can check https://github.com/palak1010/react-redux-todo-list repo for the reference:
Setup redux store

1. Create todoSlice.js file:

> ```
> import { createSlice, nanoid } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
> const initialState = {
>   todos: [{ id: 1, text: "Learn HTML", status: "Todo" }],
> };
> export const todoSlice = createSlice({
>   name: "todo",
>   initialState,
>   reducers: {
>     addTodo: (state, action) => {
>       const todo = {
>         id: nanoid(),
>         text: action.payload.text,
>         status: action.payload.status,
>       };
>       state.todos.push(todo);
>     },
>     removeTodo: (state, action) => {
>       state.todos = state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id != action.payload.id);
>     },
>     updateTodo: (state, action) => {
>       state.todos = state.todos.map((todo) => {
>         if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
>           return { ...todo, text: action.payload.text };
>         } else {
>           return todo;
>         }
>       });
>     },
>     updateStatus: (state, action) => {
>       state.todos = state.todos.map((todo) => {
>         if (todo.id === action.payload.id) {
>           return { ...todo, status: "Done" };
>         } else {
>           return todo;
>         }
>       });
>     },
>   },
> });
>
> export const { addTodo, removeTodo, updateStatus, updateTodo } =
>   todoSlice.actions;
> export default todoSlice.reducer;
> // this needs to weired up with the store
> ```

& include it on store.js file:

> ```
> import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
> import todoReducer from './features/todo/todoSlice'
> export const store = configureStore({
>     reducer: todoReducer,
> })
> ```

2. Create react component for adding the ToDo:

> ```
> import React, { useState } from "react";
> import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
> import { addTodo } from "../../app/features/todo/todoSlice";
> function AddTodo() {
>   const [input, setInput] = useState("");
>   const dispatch = useDispatch();
>   const addTodoHandler = (e) => {
>     e.preventDefault();
>     const actionPayload = {
>       text: input,
>       status: "Todo",
>     };
>     dispatch(addTodo(actionPayload));
>     setInput("");
>   };
>   return (
>     <>
>           <input
>             className=""
>             placeholder="Add Todo"
>             value={input}
>             onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
>           />
>           <button
>             className=""
>             onClick={addTodoHandler}
>           >
>             Add
>           </button>
>     </>
>   );
> }
> export default AddTodo;
> ```

3. Create component for listing the ToDo:

> ```
> import React, { useState } from "react";
> import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
> import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
> import {
>   removeTodo,
>   updateStatus,
>   updateTodo,
> } from "../../app/features/todo/todoSlice";
> function Todos() {
>   const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
>   const [selectedTodo, setSelectedTodo] = useState();
>   const [updatedText, setUpdatedText] = useState();
>   const handleInputChange = (event) => {
>     setUpdatedText(event.target.value);
>   };
>   const handleEdit = (id, text) => {
>     setUpdatedText(text);
>     setIsEditing(true);
>     setSelectedTodo(id);
>   };
>   const todos = useSelector((state) => state.todos);
>   const dispatch = useDispatch();
>   const todoTextClass = "w-full text-grey-darkest";
>   const handleUpdateTodo = (id, text) => {
>     setIsEditing(false);
>     const payload = {
>       id,
>       text,
>     };
>     dispatch(updateTodo(payload));
>   };
>   return (
>     <>
>       <div>
>         {todos.map((todo) => (
>           <div className="" key={todo.id}>
>             {isEditing && selectedTodo === todo.id ? (
>               <>
>                 <input
>                   className=""
>                   type="text"
>                   value={updatedText}
>                   onChange={handleInputChange}
>                 />
>                 <button
>                   className=""
>                   onClick={() => handleUpdateTodo(todo.id, updatedText)}
>                 >
>                   Update
>                 </button>
>               </>
>             ) : (
>               <>
>                 <p
>                   className={`${todoTextClass} ${
>                     todo.status === "Done" ? "line-through" : ""
>                   }`}
>                 >
>                   {todo.text}
>                 </p>
>                 <button
>                   className=""
>                   onClick={() => handleEdit(todo.id, todo.text)}
>                 >
>                   Edit
>                 </button>
>               </>
>             )}
>
>             <button
>               className=""
>               onClick={() => dispatch(updateStatus({ id: todo.id }))}
>             >
>               Done
>             </button>
>             <button
>               className=""
>               onClick={() => dispatch(removeTodo({ id: todo.id }))}
>             >
>               Remove
>             </button>
>           </div>
>         ))}
>       </div>
>     </>
>   );
> }
>
> export default Todos;
> ```